# Trying to follow the example for ToTraceString(), but it fails. Why?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I've got to find a way to find out what the SQL SELECT that is being generated when interacting with EF, is. I found the MSDN online help describing it [ObjectQuery.ToTraceString Method()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectquery.totracestring.aspx) and I am certain that I've followed the example exactly, but it is failing. I am getting the following error:

```
CS1503  Argument 2: cannot convert from 'string' to
'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<ResearchTableUpdates.Model.Template, bool>>'
```

I don't get why I'm getting this error. Here's the code that generates the error:

```
using (var db = new MyDbContext())
{
    int idNum = 1;
    ObjectQuery<Model.Template> oqTemplate = db.Templates.Where("it.ID = @idNum");
    oqTemplate.Parameters.Add(new ObjectParameter("idNum", idNum));
    Console.WriteLine(oqTemplate.ToTraceString());
```

The MyDbContext is a class I defined. Here is it's definition:

```
public class MyDbContext : Model.CoreFrameworkEntities
{
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        var modifiedEntities = ChangeTracker.Entries()
                .Where(p => p.State == EntityState.Modified)
                .Select(p => p.Entity);

        foreach (var modified in modifiedEntities)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            //modified.LastModifiedAt = now;
            Console.WriteLine(modified.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

And finally `Model.CoreframeworkEntities` is an EF model defined creating a .edmx file. It is one of the entities in the .edmx. (It is my understanding that any entity defined in a .edmx file is a DbContext data type. Now, if that's wrong, I'd love to know.)

I'm not sure why I'm getting the error that I am. It seems to me as though I've followed the MSDN article in code. Either the MSDN article is no longer valid or I've made a mistake, possibly in my understanding as to what the entities in a entity-relationship/.edmx file are all about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because that article uses context inherited from [ObjectContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You use context inherited from `DbContext`. That old `ObjectContext` has `ObjectSets` which indeed has `Where` overload which accepts string and returns `ObjectQuery`. However `DbContext` (which you use) has `DbSets` and `Where` methods on them do not accept strings, but only Expressions hence your error. With `DbContext` you usually either use interceptors, or `Database.Log` property, like this:

```
db.Database.Log = Console.WriteLine; // or any other handler
var templates = db.Templates.Where(c => c.ID == idNum).ToArray(); // sql will be written to console.
```

As Gert Arnold mentions in comments, you can also call ToString() on query:

```
db.Templates.Where(c => c.ID == idNum).ToString()
```

However in some cases you cannot do that (for example you end your query with `Count()`, or `First()` and so on). But when you can do that, and you need only sql for a certain single query - of course `ToString` method is better.

Comment: Or `db.Templates.Where(c => c.ID == idNum).ToString()`.

Comment: Thank you Evk and Gert. Your explanation as to why it didn't work (because the article used ObjectContext and I'm using a class derived from DbContext) makes sense. (Just an aside, I wish people would date their blog posts.) I'm using FirstOrDefault() so perhaps I should use the ToString() first and then make another C# statement using FirstOrDefault().